# consolidation of html files with their folders

Tags: 10.04

I am a linux newbie and I've been searching for an answer to this question for a long time, and I just don't know how to find it. Is there a way to associate saved html files with their "files" folders so that they can be deleted together, like in windows?

Answer (score 0):

MS Word is the only application I know that saves HTML files in a 'files' folder, and associates js/css/images to their (encoded) html page. Is that what you mean?

No browser I am aware of, not even Internet Explorer in Windows, saves entire site directories for you in the same manner as does Microsoft Word can save related items to a Files folder.

Browser files are usually saved to the 'Downloads' directory if actually downloaded, otherwise they are cached.  In either case, you have to purge individual files or all files, there is no 'convenient' association of HTML files to their image/js/css files when floating in a download or cache folder.

That said, you might investigate Star Office or OfficeLibre and see if their Writer has the same ability to save HTML pages and their associated content in a single folder as MS Word can/does.

Answer (score 0):

There is this in MS Windows:

> HTML documents can be connected to related files, such as graphics files or style sheets. When the document is moved or copied, the connected files are automatically moved or copied as well.
>   From: [Managing the File System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969390.aspx)

As far as I can tell, such a feature isn't available in Ubuntu. I'm sorry for not providing a reference because [that may be difficult in such a case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_impossibility).

Comment: Thank you for your time and for sharing your expertise. you have answered my question