# How to select/copy/move an HTML file together with its corresponding folder?

Tags: command-line, files, dolphin, html

On Windows this is working by default, because [the files are associated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/351987/consolidation-of-html-files-with-their-folders).
Situation is: saving a webpage usually creates two files/folders:

1. An `abc.html` file with the webpage's main HTML file
2. A folder with with the corresponding files named `abc_files`

Simple question:
*With which tools can I select the HTML file and get the corresponding folder selected/copied/moved at the same time?*

For example:

- Can I configure a file manager like Dolphin (or any other) to move both by selecting only the HTML file?
- Also, is there a command line way of moving/copying chosen HTML files and automatically copying their corresponding folders?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a tool called [Monolith](https://github.com/Y2Z/monolith) which works well at downloading an entire web page and all its associated assets as one file. It's a command-line tool, which you need to install, separately from the browser, but it's very handy.

Comment: Thanks. This is not a direct answer to my question, but the tool appears to be tremendously useful. Quite similar to CHM files, but probably better.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot test it atm, because of the ridiculous issues with the Firefox SNAP not opening local files...WTF? Guess I have to install the DEB version, but not today.

Comment: The Firefox snap can happily open local files, if they're in your home directory.